# How does the rails migrate works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to install devise I have run "rake db:migrate"
it was giving me an error that I was able to overcome. 
Know when I am running db:migrate again it gives me an error

```
Duplicate column name 'encrypted_password'
```

It seems that some migration commands have been run and updated the table.
Is there a way to check if I have the last migration has been run and if I have the
updated table that I need ?

Comment: check your db you must already have a encrypted_password column before adding device

Comment: You can look at the 'schema_migrations' table to see the last migration that was run. Also, if you want to roll back run `rake db:rollback`, and then you can migrate forward again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check the last migration ran, enter the following in the Rails console:

```
> ActiveRecord::Migrator.current_version
(0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" 
=> 20130617073557
```

Alternatively, you can run the following rake command from command line:

```
rake db:migrate:status
```

If indeed you have a naming conflict, I would recommend running reverse migrations on all your Devise migrations and trying again. As a last-effort stopgap, you *could* remove the line  `t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""` from your migration, but clearly, this is not optimal since it's indicating that something is wrong with your Devise installation.